# Can the Apple M1's iGPU access the entire RAM as "video memory" when training with typical deep learning frameworks?

Tags: training, gpu, memory

Can the [Apple M1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_M1)'s [iGPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Graphics_processing_unit&oldid=998862429#Integrated_graphics_processing_unit) access the entire RAM as "video memory" when training with typical deep learning frameworks (e.g., [tensorflow_macos](https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos))? If not, what memory do they use as video memory?